# Configuring memory for mappers and reducer during mapreduce job submission

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to configure memory for mapper/reducer memory during a map reduce job submission as below:

```
hadoop jar Word-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=5120 com.test.Word.App /tmp/ilango/input /tmp/ilango/output/
```

Is there any wrong in the command above ? I am getting the following exception. It looks like do we need to put JAR file or need to configure what to use -D option in Hadoop. Thanks in advance.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=5120
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:205)
```

Comment: are u using older mapred api or mapreduce?

Comment: I am using hadoop 2, which I believe should be mapreduce.

Comment: -D should be followed by a white space, as SreeVeni says

Comment: -D should be followed by a white space, as SreeVeni says. It didnt work.

Comment: For me without space also worked. I am not able to point out why satha is not able to get it worked

Answer (score 1):

Command to run a MR job is

**hadoop jar jarname classname input output**

As per your command

**hadoop jar jarname -D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=5120 classname input output**

hadoop checks Driver class with name "*-Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=5120*".
Thats why it is showing *java.lang.ClassNotFound* Exception.

**-D** option should be supplied after your **Driver** class.

Try using below command.

```
hadoop jar Word-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  com.test.Word.App -D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=5120 /tmp/ilango/input /tmp/ilango/output/
```

Hope this solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the command you provided also giving "ClassNotFoundException".

Comment: @satha.ilangovan: try -D space mapreduce.map.memory.mb=5120

Comment: Unfortunately adding space as you said also didn't work.

Comment: @satha: Now what is it showing? Are you implementing MR job with ToolRunner?

Comment: Yes I am using ToolRunner. It was showing Class not found exception again. Looks awkward to me. Thanks for your help

Comment: @satha: Try this too hadoop jar Word-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=5120 /tmp/ilango/input /tmp/ilango/output (without giving classname)

Comment: I dont think we can execute MR job without giving class name. Can We ?

Comment: Oh. I tried now and it gives me again a Class not found exception.

Comment: @satha: After doing hadoop jar Word-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  com.test.Word.App -D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=5120 /tmp/ilango/input /tmp/ilango/output/ culd you plese post the output as an edit to your question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a space after `-D` 
try  **`-D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=5120`**

There is a difference between ***-Dproperty=value*** and ***-D property=value***. The first one sets JVM system property where as the second one sets the Hadoop configuration property.

Quoting from the book Hadoop the Definitive guide, :

> -D property=value Sets the given Hadoop configuration property to the given value. Overrides any default or site properties in the
>   configuration, and any properties set via the -conf option.

Comment: I have tried like this and getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVN and added the Main class to the manifest, in this case `com.test.Word.App`, your command `-D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=5120` will be taken as input.

So, just remove the `com.test.Word.App` line